# how do i start to intergrate uber with asp.net mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, uber-api

I m currently a ASP.NET programmer and my system needs to pull data from Uber, how can i start to do this? I have gone through the [API Preference](https://developer.uber.com/v1/api-reference/) but don't know where to put in my code...

Answer (score 0):

There's an SDK for .net - https://github.com/wadewegner/uber-sdk-for-net/

If you look here, there's a sample 
https://github.com/wadewegner/uber-sdk-for-net/tree/master/samples/Web

While I normally don't like leaving 'link only' answers, this question is so broad that I feel that this is the only way to answer it!

Comment: Thanks for your solution...just wanna to ask that what is the meaning of this line in the web.config
<add key="CallbackUrl" value="http://localhost:2497/Login/Callback" />?